# CSV formatting in awk to replace quotes

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I'm parsing csv in bash using awk script. Values quoted with "

`"1";"2";"3"`

Sometimes I have not escaped quotes inside values like

`"1";"2"2";"3"` which I need to translate to `"1";"22";"3"`

How can I delete these " inside $2? First I try to check $2 if it has quotes inside but the I got stuck. If I use gsub it will remove all quotes from $2 and I'll get `"1";22;"3"`. I thought about using gsub inside gensub but did't find out how to pass function into second param of gensub.

`cat test | 
awk 'BEGIN {OFS=FS=";"} \
{if ($2 ~ /^\".*.[\"].*\"$/) {$2 = "need help here")} \
print}'`

****************UPDATE****************

Maybe there's another approach to this. Is there any special option for awk not only set separator but set quotes for separated values? It would be awesome if $1 and so on can be treated not as "value" but as value itself inside quotes

Comment: Fix the CSV generator code so that it does not produce malformed CSV data.  Kick, scream, yell, holler -- in case of emergency, offer to fix it for them -- but do something so that fixing botched files isn't necessary.  Clearly, in the short term (one-off), you'll have to hack the data, but you shouldn't have to do that, and anything more than one-off should be unacceptable.  If the quotes are meant to be embedded, they should be doubled up: `"1";"2""2";"3"` is valid CSV where the centre field has the value `2"2` when unquoted.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks but abnf says that this value is 'word' and 'word' can contain 'DQUOTE' so the only thing I can do is to change quotes from " to ' or something else but it would give me big pain in the *ss cause I need to reconfigure my production environment which is no so easy. So first I need to think of temp workaround for it.

Comment: Which ABNF are you referring to?

Comment: By any of the documented "standards" there's only 2 ways a double quote can appear inside a quoted field: `"foo""bar"` or `"foo\"bar"`. That's because the separator char itself (e.g. `;` in your data) can always appear inside quotes (which is why encapsulating quotes are necessary) so if an un-escaped quote can also appear then does `"foo";"bar"` mean 1 field containing 2 quotes and a semicolon (which would be `"foo"";""bar"` or `"foo\";\"bar"` in standard notation) or 2 separate fields? Fix the tool that's generating your non-standard, ambiguous CSV and then you'll have all sorts of options.

Comment: Note that if you're referring to the ABNF in [RFC 4180 Comma-Separated Values](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180) then (a) your data isn't comma separated, and (b) the DQUOTE has special treatment.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty: Use gsub and put back the outer quotes:

```
 $ echo '"1";"2"2";"3"' | awk -v q='"' 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=";"} {gsub(q,"",$2); $2 = q $2 q; print}'
"1";"22";"3"
```

Comment: This is simple.  The only caveat is if the input ever contains a correctly formatted field containing double-up double quotes, this loses that information.  That is, `"1";"2""2";"""3"""` is valid CSV; the second field data contains `2"2` when unquoted, and the third contains `"3"` when unquoted, but your script would lose those quotes.  I don't think it is a serious problem, but it is something to be aware of.  CSV handling in full is tricky stuff.  (You'd also have problems with `"4";"5;6";"7"` which contains a semicolon in the second data field.  Again, I don't think that's a problem here.)

Comment: Very good points, @JonathanLeffler. In fact OP says that "Sometimes I have not escaped quotes", which makes one wonder if sometimes OP has  escaped quotes! If so, a more robust solution will be more than necessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '"1";"2"2";"3"'| awk '{sub(/2"2/,"22")}1'

"1";"22";"3"
```

Comment: Funny answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet is a potential answer. The `awk` statement uses `RS` instead of FS, so each section like `"1"` and `"2"2"` are printed separately. Then the `tr` command removes all quotes. Next, the `sed` command adds the quotes back just around the entire field. Finally, the `paste` command adds the semicolons back.

```
echo '"1";"2"2";"3"' | awk 'BEGIN{RS=";"}{print $1}' | tr -d '"' | sed -r 's|(.*)|"\1"|' | paste -sd ";"
```

Comment: How does this work when there are multiple lines in the CSV file?  I know the question only shows a single line, but it is a reasonable guess that there's more than one line per file.

Answer (score 0):

Remove interspersing "'s from all fields:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\";\""}
     { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
          gsub(/"/,"",$i); 
       printf "\"%s\"\n", $0 
     }' input.txt
```

So with input:

```
$ cat input.txt
"1";"2"2";"3"
"1";"1"234"567""8";"1"2"3"4"5"""
```

you'll get:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\";\""}{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) gsub(/"/,"",$i); printf "\"%s\"\n", $0 }' input.txt
"1";"22";"3"
"1";"12345678";"12345"
```

You *really* want just $2?

```
 awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\";\""}{gsub(/"/,"",$2); printf "\"%s\"\n", $0}' input.txt
 ""1";"22";"3""
 ""1";"12345678";"1"2"3"4"5""""
```

Answer (score 0):

This should properly handle properly escaped quotes as well as malformed solitary quotes. I assume every field should be quoted

```
echo '"1";"2"2";"3""4"' | awk -F';' -v OFS=';' '{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        sub(/^"/,"",$i)
        sub(/"$/,"",$i)
        gsub(/""/,SUBSEP,$i)
        gsub(/"/,"",$i)
        gsub(SUBSEP,"\"\"",$i)
        $i = "\"" $i "\""
    }
    print
}'
```

```
"1";"22";"3""4"
```

Note, will break on `"1";"2;3"` data

Answer (score 0):

If your input CAN contain `;`s within fields then your input is ambiguous as there's no way to tell if `"foo";"bar"` is 2 separate fields or a single field and so it cannot be parsed.

If your input CANNOT contain `;`s within fields then the enclosing quotes around fields are not necessary and all you need is:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS="\";\""; OFS=";"} {gsub(/"/,""); $1=$1} 1' file
1;22;3
```

or if you feel the quotes are pretty:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=";"; OFS="\";\""} {gsub(/"/,""); $1="\""$1; $NF=$NF"\""} 1' file
"1";"22";"3"
```